# componentWillMount doesn't get called again when navigating back to my original component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

screen A: calling componentWillMount successfully and then navigating to screen B,

screen B: do some redux changes (that will affect the data in WillMount) and then navigating back to A but componentWillMount doesn't get called and preventing desirable data from appearing on the screen

```
 screen A:
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchData();
    console.log('fetched')
 }

 renderItem({item}){
    return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
 }

 render(){
    const array = Object.values(this.props.data)
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Inline>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                <Header style={styles.header} HeaderText={'EmployeeList'} 
  />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
            onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateEmp')}
             //screen B
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonStyle}>Add an Employee</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </Inline>
            <FlatList 
            data={array}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={array1 => array1.name}
            />
        </View>

   screen B:

      functionOne(){
    const {name, phone, createEmployee, shift} = this.props
    createEmployee(name, phone, shift)
   }

   functionTwo(){
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EmployeeList')//screen A
   }

   functionCombined(){
    this.functionOne();
    this.functionTwo();
   }

   and calling functionCombined in the class of course
```

Answer (score 0):

The `componentWillMount` is executed when the screen is rendered.

However, when navigating to the `Navigate` command, if the screen is first moved, it is rendered to draw the screen, but if it is already rendered, it is not rendered again.

The function shall be moved using a `push` commands to run again.

```js
functionTwo(){
    this.props.navigation.push('EmployeeList')//screen A
   }
```

Comment: the componentWillMount now gets called but now the flatlist isn't rendering on the screen

Comment: Const's `array` does not seem to get the data properly.

Comment: Array(19)
bundle.js:12587 Array(0)
bundle.js:12587 Array(0), the array gets zeroed

Comment: `this.props.data` is json??

Comment: turns out i wrote return {...state, data: action.payload} in the reducers instead of just returning action.payload

Comment: Do you normally expose your data?